# Pushing process to background causes high kswapd0

Tags: go-ethereum, nodejs, ubuntu, raspberry-pi

I have a cpu-intensive process running on a raspberry pi that's executed by running a nodejs file. Running the first command (below) and then running the file on another tab works just fine. However when I run the process via a bash shell script, the process stalls.

Looking at the processes using `top` I see that `kswapd0` and `kworker/2:1+` takes over most of the cpu. What could be causing this?

FYI, the first command begins the Ethereum discovery protocol via HTTP and IPC

```
geth --datadir $NODE --syncmode 'full' --port 8080 --rpc --rpcaddr 'localhost' --rpcport 30310 --rpcapi 'personal,eth,net,web3,miner,txpool,admin,debug' --networkid 777 --allow-insecure-unlock --unlock "$HOME_ADDRESS" --password ./password.txt --mine --maxpeers 100 2> results/log.txt &


sleep 10

# create storage contract and output result
node performanceContract.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by increasing the sleep time to 1min. Assume it was just a memory issue that need more time before executing the contract.